# accept default values in python while creating a docker image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am creating a docker image of a python project like this:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN git clone https://github.com/a/abc.git
WORKDIR abc

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python3", "./cascade.py --setup" ]
CMD [ "python3", "./cascade.py" ]
```

when the first CMD runs that is `CMD [ "python3", "./cascade.py --setup" ]`, it needs some arguments to set by the user that is as follows:

[image: arguments]

**My Question**

How do I set the default values that are **just pressing enter** or ask the user to input the values when I run  `sudo docker build .  -t pythonimg` as without this confirmation, the second command will not work and will throw errors.

Comment: Mechanically creating a PNG file like that could be a little tricky.  How did you arrive on an image file as a configuration layer?  Could you use a simpler format like YAML or TOML instead?

Answer (score 0):

Update: You can create a file with your configuration values one per line:

```
True
False
127.0.0.1
...
```

You can then save this file and copy it in your build in the `Dockerfile`:

```
...
COPY my-config.txt .
...
```

You can then feed this to your program as:

```
...
CMD python3 ./cascade.py --setup < my-config.txt
...
```

This should work.

> Note that, this is not the right way of automating image builds inside a container. You can rewrite your application to accept parameter values, in a way that it accepts CLI parameters instead of `STDIN` input.

Additionally, you can create build arguments for your `docker build` using the `ARG` instruction. (Read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)).

This way, it can run like:

```
...
# When not specified in `docker build` command, these values will be used
ARG arg1=<default value>
ARG arg2=<default value>
ENV arg1=$arg1
ENV arg2=$arg2
...
CMD python3 ./cascade.py --setup --arg1=${arg1} --arg2=${arg2} ...
...
```

You will then use these arguments in your `docker build` command with `--build-arg` switch as follows:

```
docker build -t pythonimg --build-arg arg1=value1 --build-arg arg2=value2 ... .
```

This you can provide through your automated system easily and pass onto your image build.

Comment: The application size is huge so making changes will take time. I don't want to go for that. Is there  any way I could simply use the default values? the values that are already mentioned in the application?

Comment: Maybe you can create a file with all the default values (one per line) and feed it to your program through redirecting the STDIN to feed from the file. Like `python3 ./cascade.py --setup < my-config.txt`. This will (hopefully) read one line per input and you can work on it.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: NB: you can't use JSON-array "exec form" `CMD` and also have it expand environment variables or redirect from a file.  I've changed this to use a plain-string shell form where necessary.  This also gets around a quoting problem where `CMD ["python", "cascade.py --setup"]` would consider the second argument as a single filename, including the space and an option.

Answer (score 0):

you can pipe in yes for the command. This seems to be the preferred way to do this

```
RUN yes | pip install -r requirements.txt
```